# How to connect to CFS from Spark (DataStax Enterprise)?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

We have access from spark-shell on node with [DataStax Enterprise](http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-enterprise).

In `build.sbt` there's the following dependency declared:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % ...
```

When I execute the line:

```
sc.textFile("cfs://...")
```

I'm facing the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: cfs
```

If we use Spark with SPARK_MASTER (node in DSE), we also get "No FileSystem for scheme: cfs" exception.

Q: How to get access to CFS with spark?

- should we change libraryDependencies? May be, there is another build for DSE-spark?
- settings?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE** My understanding of how to use DSE/Cassandra and Spark is almost none.

**UPDATE**: In [Accessing Cassandra from Spark](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkAccess.html) there are examples of how to use DSE to access Cassandra data from Spark. It appears that there's `sc.cassandraTable` method to access Cassandra tables. That could be the solution. Review the other links to learn about the API.

I think you should use [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) that says on the website:

> If you write a Spark application that needs access to Cassandra, this library is for you

Comment: The idea is to use only CFS "cfs://" (looks like HDFS), without using Cassandra directly.

Answer (score 0):

DataStax Enterprise Spark is preconfigured to use CFS.
So following should work:

`sh> dse spark 
scala> sc.textFile("cfs:/tmp/test.txt")`

Configuring external spark is a long story, and will require at least  to rebuild spark for appropriate hadoop version